# Configuration form with a custom control in leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, leaflet, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom control using leaflet; here you can see the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1tca13f3/

When the user clicks on the submit button, i need to read the value from the dropdown and the one from the text field.

This...

```
 L.DomEvent.on(this._container, 'click', this._doSomething, this);
```

...as predictable, doesn't work.. and I can't read the values from the input fields. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue you are having is that you are just alerting the string 'clicked' in your `_doSomething()` function. You need to look up all the values and then you can do what ever you want with those values. Here is some quick code that will at least get you going in the right direction.

```
_doSomething: function(event){ 
 if(event.target.className === 'leaflet-control-opt-submit') {
    var select = document.querySelector('.leaflet-control-opt-dropdown');       
    var input = document.querySelector('.leaflet-control-opt-input');
    console.log(select.value, input.value)
 }
}
```

it first checks to make sure the event.target is the submit button if it is it looks up the values from the inputs and for now we just console.log() them you can do whatever you want from then on with the values.